# Evaluate $\int \cos^2\theta\space d\theta$ using complex numbers.

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

> Evaluate $$\int \cos^2\theta \space d\theta$$using complex numbers.

My attempt:

$\displaystyle\int \cos^2\theta\space d\theta=\displaystyle\int\left(\dfrac{e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta}}{2}\right)^2\space d\theta$

Then I tried to simplify the integrand:

$\displaystyle\int\dfrac{1}{4}(e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta})^2\space d\theta
\\=\dfrac{1}{4}\displaystyle\int(e^{2i\theta}+2e^{i\theta}\cdot e^{-i\theta}+e^{-2i\theta}\space d\theta)
\\=\dfrac{1}{4}\displaystyle\int(e^{2i\theta}+e^{-2i\theta}+2)\space d\theta$

At this point, I'm not sure how to proceed though. I haven't learned how to integrate terms with $i$ in them yet.

Comment: By the same rules as terms without $i$ in them.

Comment: Look at $i$ as a normal constant (and that's what it is).

Comment: If you fear complex numbers, just write $\exp{2i\theta}+ \exp{-2i\theta} = 2\cos(2\theta)$ and integrate.

Comment: This is the beauty of complex and even hypercomplex domains !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just proceed the same way you would, if the exponents of the exponential function are real.

$$
\frac{1}{4} \int \left(e^{2i\theta}+e^{-2i\theta}+2\right) \mathrm{d}\theta \\
\frac{1}{4} \left(\frac{1}{2i}e^{2i\theta}+\frac{-1}{2i}e^{-2i\theta}+2\theta\right) \\
\frac{1}{4} \left(\frac{1}{2i}\left(e^{2i\theta}-e^{-2i\theta}\right)+2\theta\right) \\
\frac{1}{4}\left(\sin2\theta+2\theta\right)
$$

Answer (score 2):

From where you left off, treating $2i$ and $-2i$ as constants, we have

$$\dfrac{1}{4}\left(\dfrac{1}{2i}e^{2i\theta} - \dfrac{1}{2i}e^{-2i\theta} + 2\theta\right)$$

which is equivalent to

$$\dfrac{1}{8}\left(\dfrac{1}{i}e^{2i\theta} - \dfrac{1}{i}e^{-2i\theta} + 4\theta \right)$$

or

$$\dfrac{1}{8}\left(4\theta + ie^{-2i\theta} - ie^{2i\theta} \right)$$

In terms of $\theta$, the integral is

$$\dfrac{1}{4}\left(2\theta + \sin(2\theta)\right)$$